How to transfer my applications in visual studio with MAUI to my cell phone?
I have an Honor X8 phone and when I activate the developer options and enable USB debugging when connecting it to my computer it does not ask me if it is to transfer data or just charge, I also have the option to always ask when connecting, it also happens that sometimes I enable the USB debugging option and when I exit and enter developer options it appears disabled
I tried to update to the most recent version and it didn't work, I also looked for several tutorials but none on my specific problem

Did the problem only appear on your Honor X8 phone?

I shared something. But I have my doubts that this will apply to you. I am using another Honor model for development, without any problems, for quite some time now. Try to find something. Also, if you do not care about your data, how about resetting the phone to factory settings?

For more than a decade, I have seen this only once.
It took me the better part of the day, to figure out what is going on. The problem was some system application, having an option to persist settings.
Disabling it solves the problem with turning on debugging.
